# Adding KmlLayer using local file (File API)

Tags: file, api, kml, filereader

I am trying to load a local KML file to the map, for this I am using FileReader object (File API).

To use google.maps.KmlLayer I need to use readAsDataURL to transform to a data URL the file, the problem is that KML File is not loading to the map and I don't get any error. I think may be url attribute in KmlLayer doesn't accept data url.

This is the code:

```
gp.addEventListeners = function(){
  $("#file-upload").change(function (evt){
      var file  = evt.target.files[0]; // FileList object
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = function () {
         var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: reader.result
        });
        ctaLayer.setMap(gp.map);
      }

      if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }     
  });
}
```

What I can do? I need help :(

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to open with a web browser an html document containing a map viewer and overlaying a kml layer , all files being stored in your local file system, I'd enable localhost.

Then you can use true URLs for local files. If you google "windows 7 localhost" you can find a video showing how to enable Windows 7's embedded IIS. I have windows 7 home edition and it works.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ybn6Q92m4xg

Then, an address like http:// localhost/folder/file.kml will point to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\folder\file.kml. You only have to place files suitably.

That's what I did, I'm assuming that this is your case, too. I'm afraid it may happen that there's no workaround with these file interfaces for xmlhttprequests for these cross-source security prevention issues.

Comment: But why the exact code is working with OpenLayers. @xavigonza

Comment: they have different philosophies, you can also have offline tiles with OL. You may also use some free hosting service such as google drive, but it's not as easy.